# Irobot Create 2 drawing power from Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, irobot-create, battery, serial

I am controlling an IRobot Create 2 with a raspberry pi, which I am powering with one of these:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1566

(I know, I know, I should have just gotten power from the battery thats already in the roomba)

Anyways.  I am trying to read electric current values flowing through the roomba as it cleans.  I should be getting negative values (which I did previous to using the battery).  My code was working, although I know that doesn't mean much.

After much thought, I was wondering if maybe the roomba is drawing power through the serial port from the raspberry pi, giving it a slight charge even though it is not on the charger.

Is this possible, and is there a way to confirm or deny my suspicions?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the current seen w/o the battery and with the external battery?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so more details would have been useful.  I will post it when I get back tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ryan. You may also want to post a schematic of your RasPi, Create and power supply. You may find that [SchemeIT](http://www.digikey.co.uk/schemeit/project/) or [Circuit Lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) etc. may be able to help here. Having said that, I think this would be better off on [electronics.se] rather than here. You are more likely to get a better, faster response there.